# Hide text during a transformation (i.e. scale), making it visible only after end of transform, while keeping text size constant

Tags: html, css

Pardon the elementary question. I've built a circle that expands on `:hover` with `transform: scale(6.5)`. Inside the circle I'd like to have text hidden until the transformation is complete. Additionally the text size needs to remain unchanged (i.e. no transformation). I've tried `transform: unset !important;` and played with `visibility` but those aren't functioning as I hoped. Any help is appreciated.

```css
// this block works as expected
.expand {
  transition: transform .8s;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

// this block works as expected
.expand:hover {
  transform: scale(6.5);
}

.no-expand {
  width: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.no-expand:hover {
  transition: transform .8s;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='expand'>
    <div class='no-expand'>
      This is a circle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with pure css. Just apply a scale of the opposite magnitude to keep the text the same size and use flex to center it.

Edit: if you want the same transition as you hover over and as you exit the hover area, you can move the `transition: transform .8s;` to be applied at the div level (in this case `.circle` class).

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: transform .8s;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(6.5);
}

.circle:hover .no-expand {
  transition: visibility 0.8s linear 0.8s;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(0.154); // roughly 1/6.5
}

.circle .no-expand {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class='circle'>
    <div class='no-expand'>
      This is a circle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is very much in-line with what I was trying to accomplish. when you mouse over though the close is abrupt. what's the secret to making it have the same transition on close as seen here? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can have smooth animation on hover and out of hover by applying transition at the root level. See the edited code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is as follows:

```css
.expand {
    transition: transform .8s;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.expand:hover {
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#text {
  margin-top: 42%;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.expand:hover #text {
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='expand'>
    <div id='text'>
      This is a circle
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/xpvt214o/523382/)

Comment: I like your solution but it tends to push elements around the circle on my page down.

Answer (score 0):

new one I added font-size when you hover it, in the hover section.

```css
    .expand {
    transition: transform .8s;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.expand:hover {
    transform: scale(6.5); 
    color:white;
    font-size: 2px;
}
```

```html
      <div class='expand'>
          This is a circle 
      </div>
```

Comment: this is a good alternative but I'm running into the same issue as before with the text scaling during `:hover`.

Comment: Do you want the text to not change font size when you hover it?

Comment: Correct. I've been banging my head against the wall on how to make the text not expand with the circle. I've tested out what @rainer-plumer posted and that seems to be the best option so far. The animation of the circle closing is a bit janky but that should be an easy fix.

Comment: I made a new one check it out

Comment: The updated version is much better. But having tested out what @codecheshire posted I think I'll be moving forward with that solution.